# Cauchy Shwartz Inequality proof that uses the Pythagorean Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

The proof that I've used to understand and prove the theorem is the optimisation method. So I understand what the inequality says and why it's valid. But I'm having a really hard time visualising and intuitively understanding the proof for it that utilises the Pythagorean theorem.

This is what the proof from Linear Algebra As An Introduction To Mathematics (Lecture Notes from UC Davis) says :

"If $v= 0$ then both sides of the inequality are zero. Hence, assume that $v \neq 0$, and consider the orthogonal decomposition:

$$u = \frac{\langle u,v\rangle }{\|v\|^2}v+w$$

where $w\perp v$. By the Pythagorean theorem, we have

$$\|u\|^2 = \left\|\frac{\langle u,v\rangle}{\|v\|^2}v\right\|^2 + \left\|w\right\|^2 = \frac{\langle u,v\rangle^2}{\|v\|^2} + \|w\|^2 \geq \frac{\langle u,v\rangle^2}{\|v\|^2}$$

Multiplying both sides by $\|v\|^2$ and taking the square root then yields the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

[Screenshot of the proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jgPb.png)

Answer (score 1):

Break $u$ down as
$$
u=\overbrace{\ \color{#C00}{\frac{\langle u,v\rangle}{\|v\|^2}v}\ }^{\parallel\,v}+\overbrace{\left(u-\color{#C00}{\frac{\langle u,v\rangle}{\|v\|^2}v}\right)}^{\perp\,v}\tag1
$$
The equality follows because $u=\color{#C00}{x}+(u-\color{#C00}{x})$. The part marked "$\parallel\,v$" is a scalar multiple of $v$, so it is parallel to $v$.  We can check the perpendicularity of the part marked "$\perp v$" by taking the dot product with $v$:
$$
\begin{align}
\left(u-\frac{\langle u,v\rangle}{\|v\|^2}v\right)\cdot v
&=\langle u,v\rangle-\frac{\langle u,v\rangle}{\|v\|^2}\|v\|^2\tag{2a}\\
&=0\tag{2b}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a):}$ distributive property of the inner product
$\text{(2b):}$ $\frac{\langle u,v\rangle}{\|v\|^2}\|v\|^2=\langle u,v\rangle$

Then Pythagoras says
$$
\begin{align}
\|u\|^2
&=\left\|\,\frac{\langle u,v\rangle}{\|v\|^2}v\,\right\|^2+\left\|\,u-\frac{\langle u,v\rangle}{\|v\|^2}v\,\right\|^2\tag{3a}\\
&\ge\left\|\,\frac{\langle u,v\rangle}{\|v\|^2}v\,\right\|^2\tag{3b}\\
&=\frac{\langle u,v\rangle^2}{\|v\|^2}\tag{3c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(3a):}$ Pythagorean Theorem applied to two perpendicular vectors
$\text{(3b):}$ $\|x\|^2\ge0$
$\text{(3c):}$ $\|cx\|^2=c^2\|x\|^2$ when $c\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: so we first break down u into 2 parts : the projection of u onto v and the orthogonal portion of u (to v). So we're basically writing u as an addition of its part that's parallel to v and the part that's perpendicular to v. Do I have the beginning right? Sorry, I'm trying to go step by step.

Comment: Yes. The part marked "$\parallel v$" is $u$ projected onto the line parallel to $v$. The part marked "$\perp v$" is $u$ projected onto the subspace perpendicular to $v$. Note that the two pieces obviously sum to $u$.

Comment: Okay, I think I get it. The projection of u onto v is like one side of a right angled triangle, the orthogonal portion is another side and the actual vector v itself is the hypotenuse? This is where the pythagorean theorem comes in?

Comment: Yes. The Pythagorean theorem holds for any two perpendicular vectors. That is, if $u\perp v$, then $\|u-v\|^2=\|u+v\|^2=\|u\|^2+\|v\|^2$.